# Minitest/Mocha: How to validate the argument with a regex

Tags: ruby, minitest

How can I create an expectation with a regex in the string that the method is receiving? I'm using Mocha and Mintest.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
Logger.expects(:info).with(%r{/hello, world!/}).once
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `regexp_matches`.

Your code should look like this:

```
Logger.expects(:info).with(regexp_matches(%r{/hello, world!/})).once
```

This method is documented here: [#regexp_matches(regexp) ⇒ RegexpMatches](https://mocha.jamesmead.org/Mocha/ParameterMatchers.html#regexp_matches-instance_method).